# Using Global Sum Pooling instead of Global Average Pooling in a CNN

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, batch-normalization

I have a CNN whose basic structure is as follows,

*convolutional layers -> global average pooling -> flatten -> dense -> output*

The network that I have is independent of input size, so I could use it on inputs of varying sizes. However, the global average pooling operation uses the input size to average out all the values in a channel. For example, if I zero pad an image to change its input size, I would get a different vector after global average pooling. Therefore, I was thinking of using sum pooling instead as it is independent of the input size (I am also not sure if using sum pooling is the way to go). Since there is no in-built sum pooling in PyTorch (as far as I know), I implemented it as follows,

```
def forward(self, x):
    features = self.features(x)
    out = F.relu(features, inplace=True)
    fshape = float(out.shape[-1])
    fshape3 = np.power(fshape, 3)
    out = F.adaptive_avg_pool3d(out, (1, 1, 1))
    out = torch.flatten(out, 1)
    out = torch.mul(out, fshape3)
    out = self.classifier(out)
    return out
```

Unfortunately, after replacing average pooling with sum pooling, I got `nan` as losses, potentially because the gradients were blowing up after I multiplied the layer with a large number. So, to resolve this issue, I applied a batch normalization layer after the multiplication layer. This solved the `nan` loss problem; however, the learning (or optimization) became extremely slow. I could probably try increasing the learning rate to see if that resolves it.

But, I would like to learn why sum pooling is providing erratic results, when technically I am just multiplying (or scaling) a layer by a constant number? I would be grateful if anyone could shed more light on this. I would also like to know more about other people's experiences if they have faced any issues while implementing sum pooling.

Comment: Why do you want to enable/disable zero paddings on your input image? What's the first conv layer you are using in your CNN section?

Comment: @Ivan I can certainly use zero paddings to make all the inputs the same size, but currently, I am trying to avoid it. Additionally, I trained certain models with only smaller input sizes (say, 20x20), but now, I would like to use that trained model on larger inputs (say, 24x24). I can't really use cropping and rescaling with the kind of data I am dealing with. The first conv layer has a kernel size=3, stride=1, and out_channels=64, although I don't think it matters what type of conv layer I am using.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of stability: models are trained in the `[0, 1]` range. That being said, when you sum instead of averaging your activations, you effectively end up out of this range. This means subsequent layers will most probably *saturate* and won't be able to learn during backpropagation. This is the reason why there is no such thing as a 'sum pool' layer in PyTorch, it simply doesn't work.

Here you are training your model with say `(h, w)` inputs, and want to use it on a dataset with different sizes. You don't need to have zero paddings on the first layer, whatever the output shape of that layer. you are using an adaptive pooling in which outputs shapes with predictable shapes. So ultimately it doesn't really matter what your CNN will output. This means you can plug an arbitrary fully connected network afterwards independently from the input size. This is the main reason why adaptive pooling layers have been designed.